# Ruby Spawn not accepting a IO.pipe

Tags: ruby, process, spawn

I searched around but I cannot get to understand why I am getting the error:

```
"in `spawn': no implicit conversion of IO into String"
```

for the following simple method

```
def execute_with_timeout(cmd)
  pipe_cmd_out = IO.pipe
  pid = Process.spawn(cmd, :out => pipe_cmd_out, :pgroup => true)
  Process.waitpid(pid, 0)
  pipe_cmd_out.close
  $?.exitstatus == 0
end
```

where am I making the error here?

Thanks.

PS: I have removed the timeout code and reduce the code to what you see, the error stays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection maps a file descriptor in the child process, e.g. `:out` (or `STDOUT` or `1`) to one of:

1. io: a file descriptor specified as io.fileno
   ...
   ...

From the pipe() docs:

> **pipe() ->  [read_io, write_o]:**
>   Creates a pair of pipe endpoints (connected to each other) and returns them as a two-element array of
>   IO objects: [ read_io, write_io ].

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe

So, you can do this:

```
def execute_with_timeout(cmd)
  reader, writer = IO.pipe
  puts reader, writer

  pid = Process.spawn(
    cmd, 
    :pgroup => true,
    :out => writer.fileno,  #Redirect child STDOUT into one end of the pipe.
  )

  Process.waitpid(pid, 0)

  puts reader.gets  #Read from the other end of the pipe in the parent.

  writer.close
  reader.close

  $?.exitstatus == 0
end

result = execute_with_timeout('ls')
puts result

--output:--
#<IO:0x000001009a0140>
#<IO:0x000001009a0118>
1.rb
true
```

> where am I making the error here?

The spawn() docs say:

> For redirecting to a file, an array is used instead:
>
> ```
>  id = spawn(command, :out=>["log", "w"])
> ```
>
> The array specifies a filename, flags and permission.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn

Your pipe() call returns an array of IO objects, which you used for the value of the :out key.  But because spawn() is expecting an array of Strings as a value, ruby tries to convert the IO objects to Strings, which produces the error:

```
"in `spawn': no implicit conversion of IO into String"
```

The spawn() docs do show an example where the value corresponding to one of the redirect keys is not an array of strings:

```
 :err=>[:child, :out]
```

(which means redirect `:err`(in the child) to `child :out`).  But your pipe() array is not an array of Symbols either.

Comment: Clearly a beginner mistake! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FPEX, You're welcome.  I've looked over the spawn docs before and they are bit hard to grok.  I added some additional explanation if you are interested.

Comment: I saw it. And after your full post it is easier to catch few things I missed in the IO documentation. Thanks again.